# How to create dynamic numbers on a Bootstrap numeric button/badge?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

In my app, each user can create their own social 'group', similar to meetup.com. An example group might be "Let's play tennis on Thursday".

Users can see each group they've created from within their dashboard.

I have a [bootstrap badge](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/) which links to the users groups. This badge displays a little number indicating the number of groups that user has created.

Here's my button with a dummy number '3' inside:

```
<a href="groups" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Groups I've Created<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">3</span>
```

My questions is, how should I dynamically update the badge number so that it shows how many groups a user has created?

I have a groups table so I could count the number of rows and populate the badge that way? I've only been coding for a few weeks so if anybody can show me how the code should look at where I need to put it, it would really help!! Thank you guys.

Here's my database `Groups` data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `groups`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `group_description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

User.php

```
public function groups()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}
```

GroupsController.php

```
public function ()
    {
        $user = User::with('groups')->get();
        $check = $user->count();
        return view('groups.index', compact('check'));
    }
```

home.blade.php

```
<a href="groups" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    Groups I've Created
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ $check }}</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your User.php**

```
public function groups()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Group');
}
```

**In your Controller**

```
$user=User::with('groups')->get();
$check=$user->count();
return view('yourviewpagename',compact('check'));
```

In your blade.php

```
<a href="groups" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    Groups I've Created
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ $check }}</span>
</a>
```

Try this and let me know what happened

Comment: Thank you. When you say 'In your Controller', do you mean in my ```groups``` controller? If so, don't I have to wrap that with ```public function``` or something similar?

Comment: Yes obviously in your group controller public function

Comment: And also write your view page name.